# iText PDF issue after converting into .exe from .jar using Excelsior JET

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I had recently completed my one `JAVA` project in which i am using `iText` Libraries for generation of PDFs. Now when i run my jar file of project everything is working fine PDF file are correct but after converting my .jar into .exe using `Excelsior JET` there are certain issues in PDF.
 When i click on my `MAKE PDF` button it give an exception error [image: exception error]

and after that only blank PDF file is created with rectangle box in it.
My code of `Make PDF` is below:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
     Paragraph p =new Paragraph();
       Paragraph p2 =new Paragraph();
     String nm=id1.getText();
        Font bold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);
     try{
            String FileName="Student_"+nm+".pdf";
            String path = System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Desktop\\"+FileName;

         PdfWriter pdf = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(new File(path)));
           doc.open();
           PdfContentByte canvas = pdf.getDirectContent();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(12,12,583,830);  //x,y,width,height

   rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
    rect.setBorderWidth(1);
    canvas.rectangle(rect);

        Phrase head = new Phrase("\n STUDENT DETAILS ",bold);
           p2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
           p2.add(head);
             doc.add(p2);

           p.add("\n =============================================================\n");
           p.add("\n\n\t Student ID  :      " + id1.getText());
           p.add("\n\n\t Name         :      " + name.getText());
           p.add("\n\n\t D.O.B         :      " + dob.getText());
           p.add("\n\n\t Gender       :      " + gendr.getSelectedItem().toString());
           p.add("\n\n\t E_Mail ID   :      " + email.getText()); 
           p.add("\n\n\t Course       :      " + course.getSelectedItem().toString());
           p.add("\n\n\t Contact       :      " + id1.getText());
           p.add("\n\n\t Password   :      " + password.getText()); 

           p.add("\n\n =============================================================");
            doc.add(p);
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"'"+FileName+"'  Successfully Saved to Desktop","Success",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
       }
     catch(Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
     } doc.close();
```

All the Data is fetched using MYSQL Database

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.excelsiorjet.com/kb/30/prb-compiled-application-cannot-find-resources

Comment: Currently i am using Manual Setting. now what command i need to type in Command line box for Parsing. Thanks!  @Darzen Bjelovuk

Comment: You should look more closely at the `Exception e` you caught. In particular the stack trace might tell you more about where the file is missing.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for your suggestion but as i mentioned above the problem arises in .exe version and stack Trace is available where we do our code not in executable version.

Comment: That's a pity. How complete is the support of java then?

Comment: how to see stack trace for .exe @mkl

Comment: I have no experience with Excelsior JET. What does `e.printStackTrace()` show?